# value adding to the UITextField

Tags: uitextfield

I am trying to display a UITextField based on the OK button on the alert windows. So, when the user presses the OK button, then another textbox should come where the user can enter profile name. However, based on the code below, I see that immediately after OK is clicked, it goes on saying, that "No profile name specified" as it finds the profile.txt as empty. Here is piece of code, which displays the popup alert, prompting the user to save a profile with profile name.

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Hello, User ! Save Profile" message:@"Provide a profile Name" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK" ,nil];

profileName = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12.0, 45.0, 2600.0, 25.0)];

[profileName setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

[alert addSubview:profileName];

CGAffineTransform myTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, 130.0);

[alert setTransform:myTransform];

[alert show];

[alert release];
```

Appreciate your response !

Thanks in advance !

Comment: By using the UIAlertViewStyleDefault for the alert view, I was able to proceed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working for iOS7 with,

alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
profileName = [alert textFieldAtIndex:0];

Thanks